# Ionic display webview inside div element

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, iframe, cordova-plugins, inappbrowser

I have tabs or rather segments in my ionic application, such as Facebook and Instagram and if the user selects either of them, it should launch the corresponding site under that segment.

My html:

```
    <ion-toolbar no-border-bottom>
        <ion-segment [(ngModel)]="trendingSection">
          <ion-segment-button value="facebook" 
    (ionSelect)="segmentChanged($event)">
            Facebook
          </ion-segment-button>
          <ion-segment-button value="instagram" 
    (ionSelect)="segmentChanged($event)">
            Instagram
          </ion-segment-button>
        </ion-segment>
      </ion-toolbar>

<div [ngSwitch]="trendingSection">
    <div *ngSwitchCase="'facebook'">
    </div>
    <div *ngSwitchCase="'twitter'">
    </div>

    <div [ngSwitch]="trendingSection">
        <div *ngSwitchCase="'facebook'">
          <!--show facebook page here -->
        </div>
        <div *ngSwitchCase="'instagram'">
          <!--show instagram page here -->
        </div>
    </div>
```

.ts code:

```
ionViewDidLoad(){
  openWebPage();
}

 openWebPage() {
const options: InAppBrowserOptions = {
  zoom: "no"
};
```

but instead it loads the whole webpage ontop of the tabs(as a page), how can I maintain the webview inside the div element